# How to import .sql file on the altered table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am working on PHP project, I use MYSQL at backend and I use XAMPP to work on my machine.

I have a copy of source code in my localhost and on the online server that is on hostgator.com.

I use localhost to test my source code and after finishing testing. I upload it on the online server(hostgator.com)

Recently I am facing a problem in Database.

I applied some `alter table` queries on few tables in my database. Now I exported the database in a SQL file from localhost and importing in on live server of hostagotor.

But 'import' action is showing error(Using `PHPmyadmin` to import queries) . 
It is saying that 'Column, Column_name was not found' , i know this error is because i applied some alter table queries on few tables.

Can you tell me if there is any shortcut so that, i dont have to write those alter table queries again on the live server.

Comment: Are you importing to the existing DB with tables on Live server?

Comment: Need more details. Give the exact error and so on

Comment: @JensonMJohn yes, I am importing to the existing DB with tables on Live Server.... and this table have data also.... So, i can't replace the whole database..

Comment: @sergio : the error is 'Column Name not Found' becoz, on live server, table is present, but that table dont have the new altered column. I hope you understand. Here Error is not in question, becoz i and others also know why the error is, i need to know how to handel this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lot of research , i could not find out any shortcut. 
I wrote those alter table queries again on the table of new database and then imported the .sql file.

Answer (score 0):

One method is like You can create a new Database in your Live server & import the `sql` file you exported from localhost & change the DB configuration settings in your code.

Or

You'll have to find out the difference in DB columns between localhost & Live server and make changes accordingly.

A standalone PHP application http://code.google.com/p/phpmydiff/‎ helps to view differences between two MySQL databases. Compare the schema, data or both